# Put and delete method is showing 404 in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

0
I have been banging my head the long hours trying to figure why my PUT and DELETE request does not work. It returns a 404 not found response. My POST and GET all work fine.

I use chrome postman

```
app.put('api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {

    const course = courses.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!course) return res.status(404).send('This course with the given id was not found');

    const { error } = validateCourse(req.body);
    if (error) 
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    course.name = req.body.name;
    res.send(course);

});

app.delete('api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
    const course = courses.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!course) return res.status(404).send('this course with the given ID is not valid');
  
    const index = courses.indexOf(course);
    courses.splice(index, 1)

    res.send(course);

})

function validateCourse(course) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
    };

    return Joi.validate(course, schema);

}
```

I am trying to create a simple api in Node.js. The http method is not working

Comment: For starters, add a leading `/` to the route definitions: `app.put('/api/courses/:id', ...)`.  There is no such thing as relative routes on the server.

Comment: Then, how are you creating the PUT and DELETE requests?  Please show the client side of things.

Comment: If you really get stuck, then add this logging middleware:  `app.use((req, res, next) => {console.log(req.path, req.method); next();})` and insert that BEFORE any of your route definitions to log exactly what request is coming into the server.

Comment: There are two possible reasons for a 404 in your code: 1) the route is not found at all 2) `courses.find()` does not find a course with the given id. To find out whether it's 1) or 2) try either attaching a debugger to your code or adding some debug output in the very beginning of each routehandler.

Comment: Thanks al.. It works. The route path is wrong, I added / before api and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a leading `/` to the route definitions:

```
app.put('/api/courses/:id', ...);
```

There is no such thing as relative routes on the server.